# Creating File and copy data raising error

Tags: c#, file-io, locking

I am using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, I am working on the following code:

```
 string source =  "d:\\source.txt";
 string newFile = "d:\\newFile.txt"; 
 if(!File.Exists(newFile))
 {
      File.Create(newFile);
      string content = File.ReadAllText(source);
      File.AppendAllText(newFile,content);
 }
```

This code successfully creates the File but when it compiles the `File.AppendAllText(newFile,content)` it generates the error:

> the process cannot access the file "d:\newFile.txt" because it is being used by another process.

Why would this be?

Comment: So what is your question? Something on your system has a lock on the file and it can't read it. Remove the lock.

Comment: how should i remove the lock

Comment: @EvanTrimboli probably he did it by himself when calling [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) and ignoring the returned file handle.

Comment: Close all the connections to that file! and perform IO options

Comment: @EvanTrimboli although it has ignored but still it is giving this problem any solution??

Comment: @fayeqAliKhan how to close the connection??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `File.Create` method returns a `FileStream` object.  This is holding the file open for write.  Until that object is closed the file cannot be written to.  The best way to fix this is to simply close the returned file

```
File.Create(newFile).Close();
```

This code is essentially copying the contents of an existing file to a new one.  There is already an API available that does exactly that: `File.Copy`.  Your code could be simplified to the following

```
try { 
  File.Copy(source, newFile);
} catch (Exception) { 
  // File already exists or write can't occur 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to create file , `AppendAllText` create if not exist, you get exception because File.Create return open file stream and then you try to access same file again. you need to properly close that stream before access the same file.

```
 string source =  "d:\\source.txt";
 string newFile = "d:\\newFile.txt"; 
 if(!File.Exists(newFile))
 {
      File.AppendAllText(newFile,File.ReadAllText(source););
 }
```

**File.AppendAllText:**

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. **If the file does not exist, this method creates a
>   file**, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

but you can simply do your task by one line

```
File.Copy(source , newFile , false);
```

Comment: how would it handle if the file doesnt exist??